# opengl - unique color for each triangle

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I am trying to shade my model such that each triangle is a solid, unique color based on its position in the buffer. I would like to know if this is a proper method of doing so.

**You can skim to the last paragraph if you need no information about OpenGL**

This is my Fragment Shader that will color based on the triangles' index in the buffer.

```
#version 420 core
out vec3 color
void main(){
    float r, g, b;
    r = (gl_PrimitiveID % 255) / 255.0f;
    g = ((gl_PrimitiveID / 255) % 255) / 255.0f;
    b = ((gl_PrimitiveID / (255 * 255)) % 255) / 255.0f;
    color = vec3(r, g, b);
}
```

It uses `gl_PrimitiveID` which essentially gives the location in the buffer of the triangle it is shading. So if I do a command to draw a buffer and say there are triangles in the buffer, `gl_PrimitiveID` will say that the first one is `0`, then second triangle is `1`, and the nth triangle is `n-1`.

OpenGL has its RGB values such that they are floats between 0.0f and 1.0f (I do not know if 1.0f is inclusive and is part of my problem).

If 1.0f end is inclusive I assume the method I have displayed above will work accurately, but if it is exclusive I think that I may have to divide by `256.0f` instead of `255.0f`. Which one is proper?

**Example of replacement:**

```
r = (gl_PrimitiveID % 255) / 256.0f; // notice 256.0f instead of 255.0f
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest an alternative wich might be much simpler. You wrote:

> OpenGL has its RGB values such that they are floats between 0.0f and
>   1.0f (I do not know if 1.0f is inclusive and is part of my problem).

That is not true. OpenGL supports various different formats, floating-point, normalized integers and unnormalized integers. For your use case, I'd just suggest to use the format `GL_R32UI`, so that you can directly assign `gl_PrimitiveID` to the shader's output variable.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to compare my usage of base 256 to a case with base 10:

```
[n / (10^digit_place)] % 10
```

This formula will give the number 0 through nine at the location of digit_place (whole numbers only).

For example, if you want to get the right most digit (one's place) of `n = 1729` you do this:

**steps:**

1. `[1729 / (10^0)] % 10`
2. `[1729 / (1)] % 10`
3. `1729 % 10`
4. `ans = 9`

Making this formula more abstract:

***radix*** is a fancy term for the base number. Example: in *normal* numbers (0 - 9; base 10), the radix is 10

```
[n / (radix ^ place)] % radix
```

**The Application To My Problem:**

After doing some additional research, the rgb values in OpenGL are from `0.0f` to `1.0f` **inclusive**. This means that an `rgb` of `(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f)` is white, while an `rgb` of `(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)` is black.

In byte form (0 - 255; base/radix 256), `rgb` values for white and black are as follows (in order), `(255, 255, 255)` and `(0, 0, 0)`. Converting these values to a number between `0.0f` and `1.0f` is (again in order) `(255/255.0f, 255/255.0f, 255/255.0f)`, `(0/255.0f, 0/255.0f, 0/255.0f)`.

**Comparing to my initial shader:**

```
r = (gl_PrimitiveID % 255) / 255.0f;
```

The `r` in this example can only be between (inclusive) `0/255.0f` and `254/255.0f`. What we want is between (inclusive) `0/255.0f` and `255/255.0f` as shown above.

If we look at my calculation for `r` and compare it to the formula we see why we get a range of numbers that we do not want. The problem stems from this part: `(gl_PrimitiveID % 255)`. Because of the way the modulo works, a modulo of `n` (`n` > 1) can only give whole number between `0` and `n-1`. In this case or `n` is `255` which gives us the problem range of `0` to `254`. To solve this issue we simply replace `255` with `256` (which is the radix/base we are working with) and that makes this calculation work.

**The Fixed Shader:**

```
#version 420 core
out vec3 color
void main(){
    float r, g, b;
    // notice the 256's instead of 255
    r = (gl_PrimitiveID % 256) / 255.0f;
    g = ((gl_PrimitiveID / 256) % 256) / 255.0f;
    b = ((gl_PrimitiveID / (256 * 256)) % 256) / 255.0f;
    color = vec3(r, g, b);
}
```

Comment: Though if you want the color to be flat you should specify `flat` on the input in the fragment shader for `color`

Comment: @ratchetfreak can you explain the effect this will have? Can you please link to the docs? Thank you for the information

Comment: It stops the color from being interpolated over the triangle, so `flat in color;` will declare that only the value from 1 vertex will be used

Comment: Hmm, I am unsure this will have any effect in my program. `gl_PrimitiveID` gives the ID for the Primitive, in this case the triangle, not the vertices of the triangle, so all the vertices should be the same color.

Comment: @ratchetfreak: there is no `in` in his FS, just `out vec3 color`, so the interpolation qualifiers do not apply at all.